# What is the origin of the child don't look scene?

Tags: anime-history

If you watch some anime, chances are you gonna see that scene where the character doing something kind of out of the norm in public space and most likely a mother with her kid is passing by or stopping and then the mother proceeds to block the kid's view and saying "Don't look at that" or something like "Just ignore them / Let them be".

Anyone knows what this particular sscene is called and maybe any origin information. cause this gag seems quite used a lot but I don't really know if this kind of scene have any nickname or something like that.

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant by the origin considering this is a normal action done by parents to their children in real life. Did you mean the origin in manga/anime context?

Comment: @AkiTanaka yes in the manga/anime context

Comment: @AkiTanaka Normal in real life? I've never seen something like that in my experience. Acquaintances of mine, when asked, confirmed that they do not experience this from their parents, either. I've always taken that as something that only happens in TV.